# From "Pending balance" to "Total paid"

Tags: mining-pools

Under which conditions the accumulated amount of XMR in a mining pool, goes from "Pending balance" to "Total paid", then definitely in my wallet?
I have exceeded the payout threshold of 0.5 XMR in my pending balance, which is now around 0.53,but I still did not see the 0.5 amount moved into "Total paid".

Must a new block be found for the transaction to occur? I still did not understand completely how pool mining works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the pool payment schedule. If you go over the threshold it doesn't mean the pool will *immediately* make the payment, but it should be part of the next batch, whenever that may be. Some pools make payments once per day, so you'd have to wait a bit. Maybe you've already received your payment :)

Comment: I'm glad :) If you're happy with the answer, please don't forget to tick the "answered" box